Apply Box Constraints on the State Vector of a Kalman Filter
If in my Kalman Filter, I know my states have to be within a known lower/upper bound, is there a neat solution to this problem?
I can certainly add a constraint to this optimization problem to minimize the trace of $P$ when solving for $K$
$$\begin{align}
  \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k} & = \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} \mathbf{H}_k^\textsf{T} \mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{K}_k \left(\mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} \mathbf{H}_k^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{R}_k\right) \mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T} \\[6pt]
                       &= \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} - \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1} \mathbf{H}_k^\textsf{T} \mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{S}_k\mathbf{K}_k^\textsf{T}
\end{align}$$
$$\frac{\partial \; \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{P}_{k\mid k})}{\partial \;\mathbf{K}_k} = -2 \left(\mathbf{H}_k \mathbf{P}_{k\mid k-1}\right)^\textsf{T} + 2 \mathbf{K}_k \mathbf{S}_k = 0$$
By just enforcing that $l \leq x_{k|k-1} + Ky \leq u$
but that seems very computationally expensive when we no longer use a closed-form analytical solution but an optimizer.. Is there a somewhat reasonable solution to this? Or maybe similar to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/94952/75292 by updating from the solution without a constraint?

I derived the answer for you. It is really nice trick but it can be achieved.

The challenge in this context is the Kalman Filter does not optimize over the state vector but on the gain.
Hence the optimization must be derived when deriving the optimal gain of the given iteration.
Hence the problem is given by:
$$
$$\begin{align}
\arg \min_{\boldsymbol{K}} \quad & \boldsymbol{P}_{k \mid k - 1} - \boldsymbol{K} \boldsymbol{H}_{k} \boldsymbol{P}_{k \mid k - 1} - \boldsymbol{P}_{k \mid k - 1} \boldsymbol{H}_{k}^{T} \boldsymbol{K}_{k}^{T} + \boldsymbol{K} \boldsymbol{S}_{k} \boldsymbol{K}^{T} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
\boldsymbol{K} \boldsymbol{y} & \leq \boldsymbol{u} \\
 \boldsymbol{K} \boldsymbol{y} & \geq \boldsymbol{l}
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$
$$
Where in my case $\boldsymbol{l}, \boldsymbol{u}$ are adjusted with $\boldsymbol{x}_{k \mid k - 1}$.
For example, $\boldsymbol{u} = \hat{\boldsymbol{u}} - \boldsymbol{x}_{k \mid k - 1}$ where $\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}$ matches your case.
As I described in Kalman Filter with Non Negative Values Constraints on the Kalman Gain, the easy way to do so is with the Projected Gradient Descent.
The challenge is how to force the inequality on $\boldsymbol{K}$.
I have just answered a similar question on MathExchanmge Mathematics: Projected Gradient Descent Applies on the Constraint $\boldsymbol{l} \leq \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{t} \leq \boldsymbol{u}$.
I described the required trick for the projection using the Vectorization Operator in Orthogonal Projection onto Half Space of Matrices.

Thank you, I am just curious do you think in practice this is going to be faster than using an optimizer?  Kronecker Product looks hella expensive

@CCC, Probably when implementing the code one could do many efficiency tricks. Yet Math wise, it is the full answer. I'd think that the projected gradient descent will only need few iterations to converge.

This "answer" contains some supposition -- please don't mark it as an actual answer unless you test my suggestions.  Better, if you use it and find a better answer -- please answer your own question!
Kalman filters pertain to linear systems.  A system whose states are bounded isn't linear -- so whatever your resulting filter might be, it won't be a plain old Kalman.
Without having done this myself, I suspect that an unscented Kalman filter may be sufficient (see the comments section).  This should be well behaved, as long as you consider a tendency to never go all the way to the limits of your state bounds as "well behaved".
Construct your system description as
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf x_k &= f(\mathbf x_{k-1}, \mathbf u_k) + w_k \\
\mathbf y_k &= h(\mathbf x_k) + v_k
\end{aligned} \tag 1$$
Define $f$ such that
$$
f(x_{k-1}, u_k) = \begin{cases}
    \mathbf F x_{k-1} + \mathbf G u_k & 
         \mathbf F x_{k-1} + \mathbf G u_k \in \mathbf x_A \\
    \text{something clever} & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases} \tag 2
$$
where $\mathbf x_A$ is the set of all permissible values of $\mathbf x$, and
the "something clever" maps a potential out-of-bounds value of $\mathbf x$ back to a value that is within $\mathbf x_A$.
Note that for this to work, $\mathbf x_A$ needs to be sensible, and probably convex, such that any point in $\mathbf x_A$ has a straight line of sight to every other point in $\mathbf x_A$.  If it's, for example, pretzel-shaped then $\mathbf x$ could get "trapped" in one section.
Then build an unscented Kalman filter around that model.  It will have the -- favorable -- property that the state estimate $\hat {\mathbf x} \in \mathbf x_A$ is enforced, and the -- unfavorable -- property that $\hat {\mathbf x}$ will always be spaced away from the borders of $\mathbf x_A$ to a degree roughly proportional to the covariance.

Search the literature.  You can't be the first person to think of this.  If my suggestion won't work (if, for instance, you're trying to simulate a system that often does ride the boundaries if $\mathbf x_A$), then my next try, in the absence of a good paper on this, would be a variable-structure model that has a reduced-dimension $\hat {\mathbf x}$ sliding along the boundary of $\mathbf x_A$ -- but I'm not sure how you'd get it to come unstuck from the boundary in a graceful way without using a particle filter or some other Bayesian filter.
